# Why setting up JDE needs setting environment variable while we don't set environment variable when we install Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: java, c#, ide

Both C# and Java are managed languages, need a virtual machine to manage the code, but why VS smartly knows where the path is and Java IDE doesn't? It may be a very dumb question..but I really don't know the environment part well.. Thank you so much in advance..